# How to stack bands in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, stack

I have created an Image collection in GEE and with the help of a function I have computed NDVI index and mapped it to create another collection with NDVI as a band.

Now I want the create a stacked image with NDVI bands of the entire image collection into one image. So it should be like NDVI_1, NDVI_2 and so on...

How can I do this? I am pasting the code that shows the NDVI collection that I have so far

```
// Collection of Images 
var collection = ee.ImageCollection([feb1,feb2,Mar2,April1, April2, May1, May2, Jun1,Jun2,
July2, Aug2, Sep1, Sep2,Oct1, Oct2, Nov1, Nov2, Dec1, Dec2 ]);



//Using the following function,NDVI of the entire collection is computed
var indicesS2 = function(scene)
{ var ndvi = scene.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
  var image = ee.Image()
                .set('system:time_start', ee.Date(scene.get('system:time_start')));
         return image.addBands([ndvi]).clip(Sheikhupura);
};
var NDVIcollection = collection.map(indicesS2);
print (NDVIcollection, 'NDVI');
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that the new, better way to do this is with `imageCollection.toBands()`.

Answer (score 13):

Here is an example of creating a stacked image, using the [ee.ImageCollection.iterate()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimagecollectioniterate) method.

I also included code to define to define an example region and image collection, so that it is a working example.

```js
// Define a sample Region-of-Interest 
var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-109.1, 37.0],
          [-109.1, 36.9],
          [-108.9, 36.9],
          [-108.9, 37.0]]]);

// Define an example collection.
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
                   .filterDate('2016', '2017')
                   .filterBounds(roi);
print('collection', collection);
print('Number of images in collection:', collection.size());

// Calculate NDVI.
var calculateNDVI = function(scene) {
  // get a string representation of the date.
  var dateString = ee.Date(scene.get('system:time_start')).format('yyyy-MM-dd');
  var ndvi = scene.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']);
  return ndvi.rename(dateString);
};
var NDVIcollection = collection.map(calculateNDVI);

var stackCollection = function(collection) {
  // Create an initial image.
  var first = ee.Image(collection.first()).select([]);

  // Write a function that appends a band to an image.
  var appendBands = function(image, previous) {
    return ee.Image(previous).addBands(image);
  };
  return ee.Image(collection.iterate(appendBands, first));
};
var stacked = stackCollection(NDVIcollection);
print('stacked image', stacked);

// Display the first band of the stacked image.
Map.addLayer(stacked.select(0).clip(roi), {min:0, max:0.3}, 'stacked');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code would be useful:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/5be5a41a0a7fd12d73c9d3e42b6cf674