# Failed connection to Earth Engine servers

Tags: javascript, export, google-earth-engine

I'm trying to export a multi-layer image to drive on Earth Engine, but the task fails with the following error:

> Error creating or submitting task. Failed to contact Earth Engine
>   servers. Please check your connection, firewall, or brows

and then the message cuts off.

I've tried getting around this by logging out and logging back in, restarting my computer, and even using separate Earth Engine accounts both on my home wifi and university VPN for internet, so I don't think it's specific to one Earth Engine account or internet situation. Also tried over two days now, so I don't think it's a temporary server problem either.

Repeatable code below; wondering if anyone can provide insight.

```
// Generate Region of Interest
var ROI = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB/2013')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('cc','GL'));

// Compile the data
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2005-01-01', '2005-12-31'));

// Select the data you're interested in
var ndvi = dataset.select('NDVI');

// Prep data for export
// https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/254778/67264
var stackCollection = function(collection) {
  var first = ee.Image(collection.first()).select([]);
  var appendBands = function(image, previous) {
      var dateString = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format('yyyy-MM-dd');
      return ee.Image(previous).addBands(image.rename(dateString));
  };
  return ee.Image(collection.iterate(appendBands, first));
};

var ndvi_img = stackCollection(ndvi);
print("NDVI Image", ndvi_img);

// Export the data
// Export a cloud-optimized GeoTIFF.
// See https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/exporting
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: ndvi_img,
  description: 'MOD13Q1_NDVI',
  scale: 250,
  region: ROI,
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
  formatOptions: {
    cloudOptimized: true
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the issue boiled down to one of file size. Using a smaller (custom) polygon I was able to export the multi-band imagery. Seems to me like the error message GEE passed along was pretty useless, but who knows what came after "Please check your connection, firewall, or brows"...

Comment: I found the same thing. The shapefile I imported looked as I expected but for some reason the geometry was much larger than its extent. For some reason its geometry was for the whole globe even though it was just one country. Once I drew a geometry around my study site it exported fine. No idea how this end up with the "Please check your connection, firewall, or brows" error message