# Google Earth Engine export for asset too large?

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, sentinel-2

I am currently trying to export a rather large Sentinel-2 EVI raster of the northern coast of Cuba. The error that keeps getting returned is:

> Failed to contact Earth Engine servers. Please check your connection,
>   firewall, or browser extension settings.

I've tried to alter the code as well as log out and log back in, check wifi, quit my browser etc. but something tells me this is likely a size issue.

Heres a link to the code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/5279bd02489d430997b9e70cc751d17b

Heres a link to my area of interest to use as an import (irma80Buff):
https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/hancturner/irmaBuffers/irma_buff_80

Comment: Please post your code as part of the question, rather than an external link.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/308747/failed-connection-to-earth-engine-servers