# Is it possible to map a list with 'set' method for getting directly a list, instead a matrix, avoiding for-loop use?

Tags: google-earth-engine-javascript-api

The use of for-loops is discouraged in [Google Earth Engine](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/tutorial_js_03) because there is pointed out that the same results can be achieved using a map() operation with a specific function independently applied to each element. In following code, I have an initial list of zero values where I want to introduce ones in positions established by a list of indices of non nulls values (**idxList**). I spent a lot of time trying to find out a map operation for producing that list but, instead a list, it produces a matrix with values placed in adequate positions but it requires additional processing for getting a single list. However, the "discouraged" for-loop produces my desired solution by using directly 'set' method. Functional [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/9ec2dd50f2c651d629de0f40cdc24a8a) looks as follows:

```
var option = ee.List.repeat(0, 8);

print("initial list", option);

var option2 = option;

var idxList = ee.List([1, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]);

print("index non nulls values", idxList);

var n = idxList.size().getInfo();

for (var i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
  
  option = option.set(idxList.get(i), 1);
  
}

print("desired solution but with for loop", option);

var new_list = ee.List([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]);

var int_lists = new_list.map(function setting (ele){
  
  return option2.set(idxList.get(ele), 1);
  
});

print("result mapping a list", int_lists);
```

Is it possible to map a list with 'set' method (or using its 'iterate' method) for getting directly a desired result list, instead a matrix, avoiding for-loop use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out two possible solutions condensed in following code. The first one uses as input the matrix (list of lists) obtained by mapping **idxList** (too many lines of code compared to for-loop solution). The second one is shorter and uses 'matrixTranspose' method from **ee.Array** objects for simplifying the process. However, I'm also looking for a solution by using 'iterate' method of **ee.List** objects in GEE. I cannot find an example yet. I will accept this option as valid answer to this question.

```
var option = ee.List.repeat(0, 8);

print("initial list", option);

var option2 = option;

var idxList = ee.List([1, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]);

print("index non nulls values", idxList);

var n = idxList.size().getInfo();

for (var i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
  
  option = option.set(idxList.get(i), 1);
  
}

print("desired solution but with for loop", option);

var new_list = ee.List([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]);

var int_lists = new_list.map(function (ele){
  
  return option2.set(idxList.get(ele), 1);
  
});

print("result mapping a list", int_lists);

var list2 = ee.List([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]);

var option2 = list2.map(function(e) {

  var col = int_lists.map(function(ele) {
  
    return ee.List(ele).get(e);
  
  });

  return ee.List(col).reduce(ee.Reducer.sum());

});

print("desired solution mapping a list of lists", option2);

var option3 = ee.Array(int_lists).matrixTranspose().toList().map(function (ele){
  
  return ee.List(ele).reduce(ee.Reducer.sum());
  
});

print("desired solution by using an array", option3);
```

**Editing Note:**

I found out an example of use of 'iterate' method in this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254722/how-to-stack-bands-in-google-earth-engine/254778#254778) with an Image Collection. I adapted it with **ee.List** objects as follows:

```
var idxList = ee.List([1, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]);

var option4 = ee.List.repeat(0, 8);

var first = option4;

var appendValues = function(iter, previous) {
  
  return ee.List(previous).set(iter, 1);

};
  
print(idxList.iterate(appendValues, first));
```

It works as expected!.

Comment: Afterward I found out this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=list.iterate